# Access a VB script object within a C# .NET environment (get or set values)

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript

We have a company application for automating certain tasks (it doesn't matter what actually). In our software we have the abbility to build a script based on our own commands, were also able to run a VBScript script within the same environment. We have a function built into the software, so we can get and set variables from a VBScript script within our own script.

In our manual we have this description: "The VB script feature provides a new VB object "AppName". One of the functions are: AppName.GetStringVariable("variable"). So by just using it like this in a VBScript script it's possible to set or get this variable. You would write it like this inside the VBScript script:

```
stringInput = AppName.GetStringVariable("variable")
```

The VBscript engine is running in a different process than the C#.NET application. So this VBscript object is running in a different process, which I would like to access in my C#.NET application.

Are there any possibility to get this variable within a C# .NET environment?

I have tried:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppName.GetStringVariable(string1)");
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppName.GetStringVariable('string1')");
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppName.GetStringVariable(\"string1\")");
```

Comment: Are you hosting the VBScript engine inside your C#.NET application? Or is the script engine running in a different process than the C#.NET application? Or is your VBScript calling the C#.NET application?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying this important information. The VBscript engine is running in a different process than the C#.NET application. So this VBscript object is running in a different process, which I would like to access in my C#.NET application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the vbScript monitor a file that is updated by c# and set the property:

```
    comp = "."
    dir = "."
    select = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 10 "
    where = "WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=" & dir & "'"

    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & comp & "\root\cimv2")
    Set events = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery(select & where)
    Do
        Set event = events.NextEvent
        Wscript.Echo event.TargetInstance.PartComponent
    Loop
```

Then from c# setup a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to another file (use json, it's easy to [deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)) and get the vbScript set property.